# Firefox browser addons not syncing to android/between android devices

Tags: firefox, sync, android

Is this supposed to happen; will it be added at some point if not?

I can currently go into my android firefox for instance and install adblock plus, ghostery, https everywhere, and presumably noscript (haven't tried that one yet).

I have all that and a couple more on my desktop already and I have sync set up in both locations to the same account. On top of that, it also seems that between android devices, addon syncing also does not occur.

Edit:
According to [this](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/sync-your-add-ons-another-copy-firefox):

> Note: Add-on sync currently only works on desktop Firefox and Firefox
>   for tablets. It doesn't work on Firefox for smaller mobile devices.

To what extent does that apply. Does the sync only work between tablets for tablets or from desktop to tablet & vice versa?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most plugins for the desktop version of Firefox are not compatible in the Android version, and even if the same developer made a version of their plugin for Android devices, it would be different from their desktop version and so would not sync.

For this reason Firefox does not sync plugins between desktop and mobile versions: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/sync-your-add-ons-another-copy-firefox

Comment: That is too bad that parity has not yet been achieved on that front. How about between multiple android devices? It didn't seem to happen automatically as far as addons are concerned.

Comment: The document at the link seems to indicate this should be working. Do history and bookmarks sync across your multiple Droids?